# How do I make an image slide to the left when I hover on the image, and then after 1 second, the image slides back to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

In this project, I wrote an animation.js file that will allow a new image to slide left and right when I hover over a certain image. My function will allow the new image to slide to the left, but when I want the image to slide back to the right, I have to move the cursor away from the image. However, I want the image to slide back to the right after 1 second of the image sliding to the left when hovering over the image. How do I do that?

This is what my code currently does to a webpage(these links are random examples found from the internet):
http://static.buildinternet.com/live-tutorials/interactive-picture/index.html,

This is exactly what I want my code to do (this is my assignment):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAMjrGbmlJg

Here is my animation.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.listing_address').hover(function(){
        if ($(this).parent().is('.open')) {

            $(this).closest('.listing').find('.glass').fadeOut(500);
            $(this).closest('.listing').find('.house').animate({'left' : '25px'});
            $(this).closest('.listing').removeClass('open');

        }else{

            $(this).closest('.listing').find('.glass').fadeIn(500);
            $(this).closest('.listing').find('.house').animate({'left' : '10px'});
            $(this).closest('.listing').addClass('open');

        }

    });


});
```

Here is my listing.css file:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
p { margin: 0px; }
a { color: #bf572c; }
a:hover { color: #000; }

.house_images {
     float:left;
    }

.listing_container {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    width: 700px;
    background: url(../images/corkboard_tile.jpg) 0px 0px;
}

.listing {
    margin: 0px 15px 35px 15px;
    padding: 35px 15px 15px 70px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff url(../images/note_top.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.listing_address { margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; display: inline-block; cursor: help; font-weight: bold; color: #1f4f71; }

.listing_detail_container { height: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; color: #bf572c; }
.listing_detail { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: #bf572c; font-weight: normal; }

.listing .house { width: 40px; height: 50px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 25px; background: url(../images/house.png) 0px 0px; }
.listing .glass { width: 43px; height: 40px; position: absolute; top: 42px; left: 23px; background: url(../images/magnifier.png) 0px 0px; display: none;}

.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
        display: inline-block !important;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul {
        margin: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
}
.main-navigation li a,
.main-navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
}
.main-navigation li a {
        border-bottom: 0;
        color: #6a6a6a;
        line-height: 3.6;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
.main-navigation li a:hover{
        color: #000;
}
.main-navigation li {
        margin: 0 30px 0 0;
        position: relative;
}



#hero {
    height:175px;
    width:960px;
}
#hero div {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
#hero div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
}
#hero div.current {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is my sold.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Real Estate Sold</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/listing.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/listing.js"></script>
        <script src = "animation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="listing_container">
        <div class="header"><img src="images/header.jpg" width="750" height="150"></div>
        <div id="hero">
            <div class="current"><img src="images/landscape1.jpg" alt="landscape" width="700" height="175" /></div>
            <div><img src="images/landscape2.jpg" alt="landscape" width="700" height="175" ></div>
            <div><img src="images/landscape3.jpg" alt="landscape" width="700" height="175" ></div>
            <div><img src="images/landscape4.jpg" alt="landscape" width="700" height="175" ></div>
        </div>

<nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Regional Info</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Current Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sold</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
</ul></div>
</nav>

    <div class="listing">
                <div class="listing_address" id="martin">
                    <p>Martin House Complex</p>
                </div>
                <div class="listing_detail_container" >
                    <div class="listing_detail" id = "martin_detail">
                        <ul><li>The Martin House Complex was built in 1905.</li><li>  The square footage is 14,978 sq. ft. </li></ul> 
                        <p> <a href="images/martin1.jpg" ><img src="images/martin_ext.jpg" alt="martin" /></a></p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="house"></div><div class="glass"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="listing" id="robie">
                <div class="listing_address">
                    <p>Robie House</p>
                </div>
                <div class="listing_detail_container">
                    <div class="listing_detail">
                        <ul><li>The Robie House was built in 1909.</li><li>  The square footage is 13,070 sq. ft. </li></ul> 

                        <p><img src="images/robie_ext.jpg"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="house"></div><div class="glass"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="listing">
                <div class="listing_address" id="Taliesin">
                    <p>Taliesin</p>
                </div>
                <div class="listing_detail_container">
                    <div class="listing_detail">
                        <ul><li>The Taliesin House was built in 1911.</li><li>  The property sits on a 600 acre lot. </li></ul> 

                        <p><img src="images/taliesin_ext.jpg"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="house"></div><div class="glass"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="listing">
                <div class="listing_address" id="water">
                    <p>Falling Water</p>
                </div>
                <div class="listing_detail_container">
                    <div class="listing_detail">
                        <ul><li>The Falling Water House was built in 1937.</li><li>  The property includes the main house, a four-bay carport, servants' quarters, and a guest house. </li></ul> 
                        <p><img src="images/water_ext.jpg"></p>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="house"></div><div class="glass"></div>
            </div>  

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `animate` has a [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#basic-usage) which you can use after the animation is done. Then you can probably put something in there like `setTimeout(function(){ $(this).closest('.listing').find('.house').animate({'right' : '25px'}); }, 1000)`

Comment: @Quack Where should I place that code. I tried in a few places, and they don't work?

Comment: You need to add the callback to your animation (like in the link) und put the code in there.

Comment: @Quack I sitll don't know where to place it in my .js file, can you show me in text? I saw the example, but it still won't help.

Comment: You could do this with css only, but is it necessary to use javascript/jquery since this is an assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery [**`animate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function you can specify a callback function as mentioned in the comments above, this function will be executed *after* the animation is complete, like this:

```
$( "#foo" ).animate({
    opacity: 1,
}, 1000, function() {
    // the callback function
    alert('Animation complete!');
});
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

For your assignment, find this line in the `else` section:

```
$(this).closest('.listing').find('.house').animate({'left' : '10px'});
```

Now all you need is to add a callback function *after the closing **`}`** of your `animate()` function, like this:

```
$(this).closest('.listing').find('.house').animate({'left': '10px'}, function(){
    // this is the callback function 
    $(this).closest('.listing').find('.house').delay(1000).animate({'left': '25px'});
});
```

The callback function (the inner `animate()` function) will run *immediately* after the animation of the first `animate()` function ends, this why we added a delay of **`1`** second `delay(1000)` before it so it will wait for **`1`** second then it works

---

**UPDATE 2**

To make the `.glass` fade out too after 1 second just change this :

```
$(this).closest('.listing').find('.glass').fadeIn(500);
```

to this:

```
$(this).closest('.listing').find('.glass').fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dgqkn8ka/1/)

Comment: Thanks for you help! My teacher wants me to only use the .js file, so I cannot edit anything else. Is there another way to do this on my animation.js?

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! I just have another quick question. How can I make the image disappear after 1 second like in the video?

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, you may check this answer as the correct  one if it answers your questions